# How to insert and format a date?

Tags: excel, vba, date-formatting

This code inserts a date in column F.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim E As Range, F As Range, Inte As Range, r As Range
    Set E = Range("E:E")
    Set Inte = Intersect(E, Target)
    If Inte Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each r In Inte
        If r.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
            r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
        End If
    Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I have two minor issues.

1) The date changes if I click into E cell. It should change after I insert a value, not on click.

2) I am trying to format the date. I tried this line:

```
r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date & " " & Time    
r.Offset(0, 1).Value.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm"
```

I am getting an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
r.Offset(0, 1) = Now    
r.Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 r.Offset(0, 1).Value = FORMAT(NOW(), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm")
```

Comment: That does not return the MDY format in a system that normally uses DMY.  Using just `Now` without the format fluff gets the same result. The Format has absolutely no effect if the cell already is formatted in a different way.

Comment: I will test to see if this is true or not. I dont recall that being an issue previously but I could be wrong

Comment: @teylyn code works perfectly, thank you.Issue number 2 resolved :).Thank you.